# does if statement in datastep check for missing value

Tags: sas

Just  curious is this code:

```
data Bla.SomeGreatNewDataset;
    set WORK.InputTempDataset;
    by SomeColumnName;
    if first.SomeColumnName then output;
    else delete;
run;
```

the same as:

```
data Bla.SomeGreatNewDataset;
    set WORK.InputTempDataset;
    by SomeColumnName;
    if not missing(first.SomeColumnName) then output;
    else delete;
run;
```

in other words does:

```
if first.SomeColumnName
```

just check if SomeColumnName does not contain a missing value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

BY Group processing with `first.var` and `last.var` operates on the distinct values of the variable.  A missing value is a valid missing value.

`first.var` and `last.var` are Boolean values, either 1 or 0.  You code outputs just the first record for each unique value of `SomeColumnName`.

Note, the data needs to either be sorted by `SomeColumnName` or have an index on that column.

Here is an example:

```
data have;
input x;
datalines;
1
2
2
.
3
3
3
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by x;
run;

data want;
set have;
by x;
if first.x;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Produces:

```
                                         Obs    x

                                          1     .
                                          2     1
                                          3     2
                                          4     3
```

Comment: Ok thanks so it seems to act like a TOP 1 with GROUP BY in Sql? I am still not sure about the line: else delete; when would this occur?

Comment: That's correct on the SQL statement.  The `then output; else delete;` works the same as that "subsetting if" I have.  Replace what I have with that and you will get the same results.

Comment: `else delete` is there for completeness and understanding.  The output would be exactly the same without it

Comment: Actually the `then output` part can also be omitted and the result will be the same.  The `if` will be treated like a `where` clause and the implied `output` statement will take care of the rest.

Comment: Correct, an `if` without a `then` is called a "subsetting if" statement and works like a `where` clause.  Processing is different from a `where` but the results are the same.